# Ethereum / Solidity getting smartcontract events in the geth console

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

So I tried to retrieve the events generated by my smartcontract

```js
var abi = [{
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [{
    "name": "_value",
    "type": "int32"
  }],
  "name": "changeLowerTrigger",
  "outputs": [],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "metric",
  "outputs": [{
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "place_holder_metric_name_to_be_autogenerated"
  }, {
    "name": "value",
    "type": "int32",
    "value": "7"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [{
    "name": "_value",
    "type": "int32"
  }],
  "name": "changeUpperTrigger",
  "outputs": [],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [{
    "name": "_value",
    "type": "int32"
  }],
  "name": "update",
  "outputs": [],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [{
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "_value",
    "type": "int32"
  }],
  "name": "ValueChanged",
  "type": "event"
}, {
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [{
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "_alarm",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "_value",
    "type": "int32"
  }],
  "name": "Alarm",
  "type": "event"
}]
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

var myContractInstance = MyContract.at(
  '0x3B03c46Dfc878FeF9fAe8de4E32a6718f2E250e9');

var events = myContractInstance.allEvents();

// watch for changes
events.watch(function(error, event) {
  if (!error)
    console.log(event);
});

// Or pass a callback to start watching immediately
var events = myContractInstance.allEvents(function(error, log) {
  console.log(err, log);
});
```

But it returns only:

```js
> events
{
  callbacks: [function(error, log)],
  filterId: "0xd6af6f5a7273fe21452f00c4682456",
  getLogsCallbacks: [],
  implementation: {
    getLogs: function(),
    newFilter: function(),
    poll: function(),
    uninstallFilter: function()
  },
  options: {
    address: "0x3B03c46Dfc878FeF9fAe8de4E32a6718f2E250e9",
    from: undefined,
    fromBlock: undefined,
    to: undefined,
    toBlock: undefined,
    topics: []
  },
  pollFilters: [],
  requestManager: {
    polls: {
      0xd6af6f5a7273fe21452f00c4682456: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0xd6af6f5a7273fe21452f00c4682456",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      }
    },
    provider: {
      newAccount: function(),
      send: function github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/console.(*bridge).Send-fm(),
      sendAsync: function github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/console.(*bridge).Send-fm(),
      sign: function(),
      unlockAccount: function()
    },
    timeout: {},
    poll: function(),
    reset: function(keepIsSyncing),
    send: function(data),
    sendAsync: function(data, callback),
    sendBatch: function(data, callback),
    setProvider: function(p),
    startPolling: function(data, pollId, callback, uninstall),
    stopPolling: function(pollId)
  },
  formatter: function(),
  get: function(callback),
  stopWatching: function(callback),
  watch: function(callback)
}
```

But what I want, is the events shown in the next image at the very bottom(e.g.Value Changed value:7):
[image]

Since the events are displayed in the ETH-Wallet there should be a way. I rly just want a way to get the latest events in the geth console (or sth similare).
Thanks for any help I'm kinda lost and having some of the worst googling of my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to call `get()` on the result object you've got and posted in your answer. Its described in official documentation and can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example-54)

Comment: Found an API for it/(other things) eventually but great to see an answer after all this time^^